# C# Request path comparison with router path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to compare below two strings using c# asp.net core. The motivation is to compare two paths except path parameter (without manually splitting and comparing one by one). Is it possible to do this in single line using any in-build method?

**Requested:** /api/v1/schedules/S210715001/comments

**Original:** /api/v1/schedules/{id}/comments

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use regex `\/api\/v1\/schedules\/.+\/comments`
but I'm not sure why would you do that

Comment: This seems like an XY problem, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DavidG unfortunately I have a requirement to compare the browser requested path against the list of router paths.

Comment: That's not a requirement, it's a path towards some other actual requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a regex pattern of the original string containing curly brackets and then match against the requested string.

```
string original = @"/api/v1/schedules/{id}/comments";
string requested = @"/api/v1/schedules/S210715001/comments";

string originalPattern = Regex.Replace(original, @"\{[^\}]*\}", @"\w*");
var isMatch = Regex.Match(requested, $"^{originalPattern}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. This really helps. Strangely, it does not considering the change in the original text, next to path parameter and always return true. e.g.string original = @"/api/v1/schedules/{id}/";

Comment: Add a 'start of string' and 'end of string' like this:
var isMatch = Regex.Match(requested, $"^{originalPattern}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;

Comment: I guess this is the most helpful answer. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in fuction called `Path.GetFileName` in `System.IO` allowing you to extract a file name from a whole path.

Here is how to use it:

```cs
    var original = "/api/v1/schedules/S210715001/comments";

    var requested = "api/v1/schedules/{id}/comments";
            
    Console.WriteLine("original: " + Path.GetFileName(original));
    Console.WriteLine("requested: " + Path.GetFileName(requested));
```

output:

> original: comments
>
> requested: comments

Note : there are some subtilities on what is considered a directory separator : backslash, forward slash etc. (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar?view=net-5.0)), but I think it's easier to use than regular expressions.